# Indent value from array in php like a table

Tags: php

I've an array like:

```
$array = array(
  0 => "A",
  1 => "B",
  2 => "C",
  3 => "D",
  4 => "E",
  5 => "F",
  6 => "G",
  7 => "H",
);
```

Max lenght `$array` can be is 9, so max is `index = 8` and min is 0 (at least 1 element inside array).
I've to indent this list inside a TCPDF box with limited height where, with some test, i've seen can support max 3 lines. But this box is large so, when the array lenght is bigger than 3, the others element need to be aligned in the side of the first column created like:

```
A    D    G
B    E    H
C    F
```

I can't use X,Y coordinated cause i'm using writeHTML method in TCPDF.

I need to create 3 strings like:

```
$line1 = "A   D   G";
$line2 = "B   E   H";
$line3 = "C   F";
```

What's the best method to create this 3 variables from my array?

UPDATE: using suggest method array_chunk is not the solution for me cause for my purpose I'd like to receive an array like:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array (
                [0] => A
                [1] => D
                [2] => G
           ) 
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => B 
                [1] => E 
                [2] => H 
           )
            [2] => Array ( 
                [0] => C 
                [1] => F )
           )
```

Comment: _What's the best method to create..._ What methods have you been trying?

Comment: Try `array_chunk`

Comment: I've tried to create a cicle FOR with $index, create a $temp_array on each cycle. and insert the element. and when $index increment and is equal to 2 i've to get $temp_array already created and append the values from 3 to 5 each in the correct $temp_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `for` loop can solve OP's problem. This is another possible solution that use PHP array functions:

```
<?php

$array = array(
  0 => "A",
  1 => "B",
  2 => "C",
  3 => "D",
  4 => "E",
  5 => "F",
  6 => "G",
  7 => "H",
);

$cols = 3;

$array = array_chunk($array, $cols);

$results = array_map(function($index) use ($array) {
  return array_column($array, $index);
}, range(0, $cols - 1));

var_dump($results);
```

View online here: https://eval.in/945787

Comment: It works like expected with only few lines of code!! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$array = array(
    0 => "A",
    1 => "B",
    2 => "C",
    3 => "D",
    4 => "E",
    5 => "F",
    6 => "G",
    7 => "H",
);
$array_chunk = array_chunk($array, 3,false);
$line = '';
foreach ($array_chunk as $chunk_key => $chunk_value) {
    $line = '"';
    foreach ($chunk_value as $key => $value) {
        $line.=$value." ";
    }
    $line = "$" . "line" . ($chunk_key+1) . " = " . rtrim($line, " ") . '"' . "<br/>";
    echo $line;
    $line='';
}
```

**Demo**
[image]